# Related to pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
void pushathead(struct Node* head, int data){
  struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  new_node->data = data;
  new_node->next = head;
  head = new_node;
}
void pushathead(struct Node** head, int data){
  struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  new_node->data = data;
  new_node->next = (*head);
  (*head) = new_node;
}
```

Can anyone explain the difference between the two methods, and which one should be used for implementation?

Comment: can u explain why **head is passed in the second method instead of *head?

Answer (score 1):

The first implementation accepts a pointer argument to the head of your linked list.

The second implementation accepts a pointer to a pointer to the head of your linked list.

Can you tell why that might be important?

You want to use the second one, otherwise you will lose any reference to the new node being created.

In other words, the first implementation is just modifying a local copy of `head`, the last line `head = new_node;` is meaningless, doing effectively nothing because it's working on a local value. The second implementation will modify a pointer on the outside.

First will be called like this:

```
Node *head = NULL; // declared somewhere
pushathead( head, 1 );
```

And the second will be called like this:

```
Node *head = NULL;
pushathead( &head, 1 );
```

Using the address-of operator here is a big hint that `head` is going to be modified, and that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a third choice:

```
struct Node* pushathead(struct Node* head, int data){
  struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  new_node->data = data;
  new_node->next = head;
  return new_node;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Node *list = NULL; // declared somewhere
list = pushathead( list, 10 );
list = pushathead( list, 20 );
```